# Code inside thread slower than outside thread..?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, final

I'm trying to alter some code so it can work with multithreading. I stumbled upon a **performance loss when putting a Runnable around some code**.

For clarification: The original code, let's call it

```
//doSomething
```

got a Runnable around it like this:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //doSomething
    }
}
```

Then I submit the runnable to a ChachedThreadPool ExecutorService. This is my first step towards multithreading this code, to see if the code runs as fast with one thread as the original code.

However, this is not the case. Where *//doSomething* executes in about 2 seconds, the Runnable executes in about 2.5 seconds.  **I need to mention that some other code, say, *//doSomethingElse*, inside a Runnable **had no performance loss** compared to the original *//doSomethingElse*.**

My guess is that *//doSomething* has some operations that are not as fast when working in a Thread, but I don't know what it could be or what, in that aspect is the difference with *//doSomethingElse*.

Could it be the use of **final int[]/float[]** arrays that makes a Runnable so much slower? The *//doSomethingElse* code also used some finals, but *//doSomething* uses more. This is the only thing I could think of.

Unfortunately, the *//doSomething* code is quite long and out-of-context, but I will post it here anyway. For those who know the Mean Shift segmentation algorithm, this a part of the code  where the mean shift vector is being calculated for each pixel. The for-loop

```
for(int i=0; i<L; i++)
```

runs through each pixel.

```
timer.start(); // this is where I start the timer
// Initialize mode table used for basin of attraction
char[] modeTable = new char [L]; // (L is a class property and is about 100,000)
Arrays.fill(modeTable, (char)0);
int[] pointList = new int [L];

// Allcocate memory for yk (current vector)
double[] yk = new double [lN]; // (lN is a final int, defined earlier)

// Allocate memory for Mh (mean shift vector)
double[] Mh = new double [lN];

int idxs2 = 0; int idxd2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    // if a mode was already assigned to this data point
    // then skip this point, otherwise proceed to
    // find its mode by applying mean shift...
    if (modeTable[i] == 1) {
        continue;
    }

    // initialize point list...
    int pointCount = 0;

    // Assign window center (window centers are
    // initialized by createLattice to be the point
    // data[i])
    idxs2 = i*lN;
    for (int j=0; j<lN; j++)
    yk[j] = sdata[idxs2+j]; // (sdata is an earlier defined final float[] of about 100,000 items)

    // Calculate the mean shift vector using the lattice
    /*****************************************************/
    // Initialize mean shift vector
    for (int j = 0; j < lN; j++) {
        Mh[j] = 0;
    }
    double wsuml = 0;
    double weight;

    // find bucket of yk
    int cBucket1 = (int) yk[0] + 1;
    int cBucket2 = (int) yk[1] + 1;
    int cBucket3 = (int) (yk[2] - sMinsFinal) + 1;
    int cBucket = cBucket1 + nBuck1*(cBucket2 + nBuck2*cBucket3);
    for (int j=0; j<27; j++) {
        idxd2 = buckets[cBucket+bucNeigh[j]]; // (buckets is a final int[] of about 75,000 items)
        // list parse, crt point is cHeadList
        while (idxd2>=0) {
            idxs2 = lN*idxd2;
            // determine if inside search window
            double el = sdata[idxs2+0]-yk[0];
            double diff = el*el;
            el = sdata[idxs2+1]-yk[1];
            diff += el*el;
            //...
            idxd2 = slist[idxd2]; // (slist is a final int[] of about 100,000 items)
        }
    }
    //...
}
timer.end(); // this is where I stop the timer.
```

There is more code, but **the last while loop** was where I first noticed the difference in performance.

Could anyone think of a reason why this code runs slower inside a Runnable than original?

Thanks.

**Edit: The measured time is *inside* the code, so *excluding* startup of the thread.**

Comment: If you take something that runs 260ms, wrap it in a Runnable, and run it only once, then yes, it will take longer because of the thread startup overhead.  Running something once is not a good use of threading.  Please explain why you want to run this multi-threaded.

Comment: I mentioned that the other code was just as quick inside the Runnable as outside. But indeed, the total running time was longer with that one. This code, when complete, takes about 3.5 seconds inside the Runnable, in comparison to 2 seconds outside. I want to run this code multi-threaded as part of a supposed-to-be realtime application. The giant for-loop (from 0 to L) can be split into parts.

Comment: In the light of your edit, how does the parallelized code (and the test) look?

Comment: @gustafc: the "parallelized" code looks just the same as the code I posted, only then pasted into the run() method of a Runnable. The timer will also be inside the run() method. The Runnable is then submitted to an ExecutorService. I know this is not yet really parallel, but if this works correctly, I can split the great loop into multiple Runnables.

Comment: What is the original thread doing? Is that the AWT event thread? By moving functionality from the AWT event thread to another thread, the AWT event thread might spend CPU cycles on repainting the screen, which might slow down your new thread.

Answer (score 3):

All code always runs "inside a thread".

The slowdown you see is most likely caused by the overhead that multithreading adds. Try parallelizing different parts of your code - the tasks should neither be too large, nor too small. For example, you'd probably be better off running each of the outer loops as a separate task, rather than the innermost loops.

There is no single correct way to split up tasks, though, it all depends on how the data looks and what the target machine looks like (2 cores, 8 cores, 512 cores?).

**Edit:** What happens if you run the test repeatedly? E.g., if you do it like this:

```
Executor executor = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int lap = i;
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //doSomething
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.printf("Lap %d: %d ms%n", lap, duration);   
        }
    };
    executor.execute(r);
}
```

Do you notice any difference in the results?

Comment: Well actually the complete task is quite large (takes 2 seconds). Sorry I didn't mention that. The overhead would then currently be 500 ms and I don't believe that. Also, I measure time within the code.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not see any reason for this. Any program has at least one thread. All threads are equal. All threads are created by default with medium priority (5). So, the code should show the same performance in both the main application thread and other thread that you open.

Are you sure you are measuring the time of "do something" and not the overall time that your program runs? I believe that you are measuring the time of operation together with the time that is required to create and start the thread.

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure of that, as I've edited into my original post ;) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new thread you always have an overhead. If you have a small piece of code, you may experience performance loss.
Once you have more code (bigger tasks) you make get a performance improvement by your parallelization (the code on the thread will not necessarily run faster, but you are doing two thing at once).

Just a detail: this decision of how big small can a task be so parallelizing it is still worth is a known topic in parallel computation :)

Comment: Actually the complete task is quite large, as I've now edited into my original post. Takes 2 seconds to complete (vs. 2.5 seconds using Runnable). 500 ms is a little too much overhead, I think.

Comment: I think the math you should do is: how long does it take to your whole program execute in a single thread and how long does it take to execute in a parallel fashion. 
This extra 500ms could be caused by other threads preempting "yours", I would guess :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained exactly how you are measuring the time taken. Clearly there are thread start-up costs but I infer that you are using some mechanism that ensures that these costs don't distort your picture.

Generally speaking when measuring performance it's easy to get mislead when measuring small pieces of work. I would be looking to get a run of at least 1,000 times longer, putting the whole thing in a loop or whatever.

Here the one different between the "No Thread" and "Threaded" cases is actually that you have gone from having **one** Thread (as has been pointed out you **always** have a thread) and *two* threads so now the JVM has to mediate between two threads. For this kind of work I can't see why that should make a difference, but it is a difference.

I would want to be using a good profiling tool to really dig into this.

Comment: I've added my timing methods to my original post. It is outside the large loop and totals to about 2 seconds (vs 2.5 seconds using Runnable). About the one vs two threads, would this still be a problem if the first thread (the one that started the second thread) waited for the second thread to finish?

Comment: I doubt that it's even a problem anyway, I think we can easily imagine that if both threads were really busy then there's extra work, but I don't see how that applies in your case.